# Chrome box-shadow inset with rgba bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've encountered a weird bug i cannot solve.
I have a div background that includes a css background image and a box-shadow that does overlay box shadow with rgba to darken the background..

At first load, it seems fine, but when i hover over a button element it changes the rgba for the whole line. pretty weird.

HTML :

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="bigimage" style="background-image: url(http://s3-ak.buzzfeed.com/static/2014-06/25/22/campaign_images/webdr07/the-one-detail-you-missed-from-captain-america-th-2-1617-1403749709-24_dblbig.jpg);">
    <div class="container">
         <h1 id="maintitle">The One Detail You Missed From "Captain America: The Winter Soldier"</h1>
 <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="http://www.buzzfeed.com/javiermoreno/the-one-detail-you-missed-from-captain-america-the-winter-so" id="mainlink" role="button">Read more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bigimage {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 610px 155px inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 610px 155px inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 610px 155px inset;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
    /* -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 25px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Sample image:

[image]

Comment: Any chance we can see some code?

Comment: i've updated with more css and html structure.

Comment: Where is the CSS for your `:hover` ?

Comment: http://assets.pbdm.link.s3.amazonaws.com/core2.css

Comment: Do you see the issue here? http://jsfiddle.net/6sGkN/1/

Comment: Nop its not shown there. http://a.pbdm.link/e53deb/growth-hacking-israel-conference-tickets-tel-aviv---eventbrite you can see here its happening.

Comment: Then it must be coming from some other css on your page that you haven't posted here